# How can I make Kryo Serializer

Tags: kotlin, apache-flink, jena

I tried to solve the following problem by providing Kryo Serializer but it still doesn't work. It could not recognize the serializer of ModelCom. Also, any messages by print function don't show up.

I used Apache Flink  1.9.0 and Apache Jena 3.10.0

My code in Kotlin:

```
val serializer = object : Serializer<Model>(){
            override fun write(kryo: Kryo, output: Output?, obj : Model?) {
                print("write")
                kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, obj)
            }

            override fun read(kryo: Kryo, input: Input?, type: Class<Model>?): Model {
                print("read")
                val m = kryo.readObject(input, Model::class.java)
                return m
            }

        }


ExecutionContext.see.config.registerTypeWithKryoSerializer(ModelCom::class.java, serializer::class.java)
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskException: Cannot serialize operator object class org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.SimpleUdfStreamOperatorFactory.
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.setStreamOperatorFactory(StreamConfig.java:222)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.setVertexConfig(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:460)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createChain(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:272)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createChain(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:243)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createChain(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:243)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.setChaining(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:207)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createJobGraph(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:159)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamingJobGraphGenerator.createJobGraph(StreamingJobGraphGenerator.java:94)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamGraph.getJobGraph(StreamGraph.java:737)
    at org.apache.flink.optimizer.plan.StreamingPlan.getJobGraph(StreamingPlan.java:40)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.LocalStreamEnvironment.execute(LocalStreamEnvironment.java:86)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1507)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1489)
    at core.EgressEngine.start(EgressEngine.kt:187)
    at core.EgressEngineKt.main(EgressEngine.kt:45)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.serializeObject(InstantiationUtil.java:586)
    at org.apache.flink.util.InstantiationUtil.writeObjectToConfig(InstantiationUtil.java:515)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.graph.StreamConfig.setStreamOperatorFactory(StreamConfig.java:219)
    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jena models are not serializable, so this approach isn't going to work. What you could do instead would be to send around just enough serialized data so that each instance that needs a model can instantiate one.

See [this thread](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/jena-users/201906.mbox/%3Cc2dc7183-a7fc-366f-3ce1-fb7d68edced0@apache.org%3E) from the jena-users list about how to resolve this for Spark; the underlying issues are the same for any JVM-based framework that distributes computation.